# PostgreSQL+PostGIS function that gives angular seperation for a pair of (lat,long) points

Tags: postgresql, postgis, user-defined-functions

I wrote the following code (after spending a few *hours* trying to get the quoting correct):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ast3angsep(double precision, double precision, double precision, double precision) RETURNS double precision AS $$
SELECT ST_Distance( ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT('||$1||' '||$2||')'), ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT('||$3||' '||$4||')') )/6370986.0/PI()*180.0;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

This function works but, unfortunately, it's precision is HORRIBLE. It seems like there should be a much simpler way to do this. I just want to pass the values to the function and have it pass them to the ST functions. I was completely unable to find a way of doing this without converting them to string first, which is probably where the loss of precision enters.

Am I doing this totally screwed up?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting to strings and creating a point using `ST_GeographyFromText`, try using [ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) directly with the values received by the funciton.